# Proving $A$ similar to $B$, unable to find a valid $P$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, similar-matrices

Let *$D$* denote the set of all $2\times2$ diagonal matrices. Consider an ordered basis $$β=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

$T:D\to R^{2}$ is defined as $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a+b, 4a-5b)$$

Let Matrix $A$ be matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t $β$ for domain, and standard ordered basis for codomain.

Let Matrix $B$ be matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t $β$ for domain, and ordered basis $\{(1,-1), (1,1)\}$ for codomain.

Prove that $A$ is similar to $B$.

I have calculated $A$ and $B$, but unable to find any $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: You wrote the adequate $P$ in your statement, look closer